# Testcafe tests crash after login (corporate website redirection fails)

Tags: javascript, testing, proxy, server, testcafe

I am having this issue since a couple of days. I started using testcafe but i can't login properly. Here is my first test :

```
const role = Role('https://mywebsite.com', async t => {
    await t.typeText(authenticationPage.loginInputBox, user.login)
    .typeText(authenticationPage.passwordInputBox, user.password)
    .click(authenticationPage.signInButton);
}, { preserveUrl: true });

export default async () => {
    await navigate_as();
};

async function navigate_as() {
    await t
        .setTestSpeed(0.1)
        .useRole(role)
        .navigateTo("https://mywebsite.com/#/dashboard");
    await t
        .click(portfolioPage.navigateAs)
        .typeText(portfolioPage.navigateAsInput, "John Doe")
.expect(portfolioPage.navigateAsAutocomplete.exists).notOk({timeout: 10000});
}
```

The problem is that the server usually redirects to the dashboard, but with testcafe after the first login redirection to the dashboard, it stays here 1 second and redirects to an error page. It says 502 bad gateway like below (so the tests crash after that) :

[image]

Is there anyone who had this problem and could tell me what's happening ? Is it something I can do with testcafe configuration to work around this ?
I am using last version of node (v10.4.1) and tried with IE, Firefox and Chrome, same result with tescafe (v0.18.6) (Windows 7 OS)

The code without using roles is the following, it gives the same result:

```
async function sign_in_with_sso() {
    await t
            .setTestSpeed(1)
            .typeText(authenticationPage.loginInputBox, user.login)
            .typeText(authenticationPage.passwordInputBox, user.password)
            .click(authenticationPage.signInButton)
            .expect(authenticationPage.formIsLoading.exists).notOk({timeout: 10000});
}
```

Thank you,

Comment: Have you tried to perform login action without creating and using the Role? Could you please try to copy your login actions into the test code?

Comment: mywebsite.com is not available. If this is just a fake URL, specify your URL so that it can be possible to check the issue locally. In addition, clarify which browser, OS, TestCafe and node.js versions you are using.

Comment: @AndreyBelym Yes I already tried that. I just put the code above, thank you

Comment: Your code looks valid. If the latest testcafe version (1.1.2 at the moment) still has this behavior, please [submit a new issue](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md) and provide the team with a simple sample to replicate it, so they can examine your scenario and find a suitable solution.